# Triggering Class Which Extends PTransforms one After One?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, cloud, apache-beam, dataflow

I have 2 classes which extend `PTransform`, called `CompositeCall2` and  `CompositeCall`.

I have to call `CompositeCall` first and then, after completion of the work done in `CompositeCall`, I have to call `CompositeCall2` in my dataflow program. I am making template of my dataflow job so parallel processing is going on which makes my work difficult.

Code.:Tester.java

```
package Testing2;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner;
import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Description;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Validation;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.View;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollectionView;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PDone;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;

public class Tester {

    public interface FileData extends PipelineOptions {
         @Description("name Of the File")
         @Validation.Required
         ValueProvider<String> getInputFile();
         void setInputFile(ValueProvider<String> value);

         @Description("Path Of File From Where We need To Read Data")
         @Validation.Required
         ValueProvider<String> getOutputFile();
         void setOutputFile(ValueProvider<String> value);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        DataflowPipelineOptions options=PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
        options.setProject("testing1-180111");
        options.setTempLocation("gs://kishan-bucket/staging");
        options.setTemplateLocation("gs://kiss-bucket/templates/Test1");
        options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        PDone dta = p.begin().apply("Creating File",Create.of("Kishan")).apply(new CompositeCall(p));
        p.apply("Creating File",Create.of("Kishan")).apply(new CompositeCall2(p));
        p.run().waitUntilFinish();  
    }
}
```

This is the way I am calling.
Both classes are doing the same work, just printing data in a file and writing that data.

package Testing2;

```
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollectionView;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class CompositeCall2 extends PTransform <PCollection<String>,PCollection<String>> {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static Pipeline p;

    public CompositeCall2(Pipeline p1) {
        this.p = p1;
    }
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CompositeCall2.class);

    @Override
    public PCollection<String> expand(PCollection<String> input) {
        PCollection<String> data;
        input.apply(ParDo.of(new testing())).apply(TextIO.write().to("gs://kiss-bucket/test1.txt"));
        LOG.info("Enter Second Stage Called");
        return input;           
    }

    static class testing extends DoFn<String,String>{

        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws InterruptedException{
            LOG.info("Enter Second Stage");
            c.output("Data Is"+c.element());
        }
    }
}
```

How can I synchronize the flow so that after one transformation another transform runs?

Answer (score 0):

This a bit old but I came across it today and thought I might share for others that are having a similar issue - there is a [Wait.on](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Wait.html) transform allows you to wait for a prior transform to complete before applying a later operation.